# Third party integration (required at runtime) in maven

Tags: maven-3

I am new to maven. I have used ant and know how to bundle third party jars with my jars so that they should be available at runtime. I am writing an application which depends on Apache tika library. I am using dependency to include Apache Tika jar. And my jar gets generated successfully. My pom.xml file is

```
<groupId>com.nayan.parsers</groupId>
<artifactId>nayantikaparser</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>tika-app</artifactId>
                                    <version>0.7</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

At the runtime since Tika will not be available on all systems I want to bundle classes from Tika jar into my output jar. But I am not sure how to do that. I ant I used to do it in the following way

```
     <zip destfile="dist/${jar.name}-${build.version}.jar">         
    <!-- Include the temporary jar -->
    <zipgroupfileset file="dist/temp.jar" />

    <zipgroupfileset file="lib/tika-app-1.3.jar"/>          
</zip>
```

How to do the same using maven.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). Specifically, [jar-with-dependecies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) case. This will ensure all the dependencies are in the jar.

If you want finer control look into [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). See [this case](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response Nishant.I was looking into [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) and modified my pom.xml accordingly.
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>copy</id>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
<goal>shade</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<artifactSet>
<includes>
<include>org.apache.tika:tika-app</include>
</includes>
</artifactSet>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
Still no classes for tika in my jar. It was not added.

Answer (score 0):

Its too late to update but I was able to achieve the desired results. I used shade plugin for maven

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.testng</exclude>
                                <exclude>log4j</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>                          
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```